# OpenCV - Ellipse contour detection

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have a mask with outlines of ellipses. I am trying to locate their centers. So far I tried using `cv2.HoughCircles`, but that does not work properly.

I tried scaling the image so that ellipses become more like circles, but that does not work with `cv2.HoughCircles` either.

Outlines are not continuous so I tried morphological operations, but the gaps are very large and by the time I close gaps on a larger ellipse, the smaller ones are gone.

Any suggestions?

[image: elipses]

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35651948/5008845). I recommend the methods of Prasad or Libuda for this kind of images

Comment: @Miki thanks for the link, there is a lot of information. that will keep me busy for a while.