# Shape ellipse like detection with varying edge intensity

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-recognition

I need some help, I'm struggling to detect an ellipse-like shape in C++ or Python.

At first glance it's clear there is a boundary of the shape though the edges are not homogeneous. I tried many OpenCV algorithms like blob detection or findcontours but with out any luck.

Clearly, because of non homogeneous edges the detection algorithm should be local and not global.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

Input and desired output in red:

[image]        [image]
[image]        [image]

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35651948/5008845) and its links

Comment: "At first glance it's clear there is a boundary of the shape": no, there are places where it is fuzzy, a bad trap for any segmentation algorithm. Even humans wouldn't return consistent results. Try active contours.