# How to detect a visual code (shape) and check in OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, detection

I need to detect and the check visual codes that I have designed as the below images

[image: pic]

I will stick that visual code on sidewalks so user can read it by android real time camera view and depends on which dots blacked, takes act. Just like snapchat id but more simple as 24 different possibilty.

Its does not sound good to detect circles on view, so as a beginner how to make it in an effective way?

**A Different Picture**

[image: a different]

**And one more Different picture of the code**

[image: and one more different picture of code]

Comment: It seems better to use ready to use AR libs, like aruco for instance: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html

Comment: 1) See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32798574/5008845) to know why you need ellipse detection instead of circle detection. 2) your 2nd and 3rd marker are different only up to a rotation. This is **not** a good idea, especially if you plan to recognize each one using a smartphone 3) OpenCV can detect Aruco, so your project is still in OpenCV. 4) Just use an Aruco marker, it'll make your life much easier.